# Server-side dynamic Flash export to video

Tags: php, facebook, apache, flash, video

I have spend some time hunting around for a solution without success so I am hoping someone here can at least point me in the right direction.

The specific project flow is this:

- user visits a Facebook app
- user uploads a number of photos and chooses optional filters
- user can preview a video which showcases their photos (the video has animation and audio)
- user can then choose to download this video for their device/PC

Some givens:

- server side is PHP on Linux/Apache
- preview video is Flash
- output format is variable (WMV/AVI/MP4)

I have found a couple of solutions but none seem to match this exact flow. I want the whole process to be automated/scripted so need a component that can sit on the server, accept commands from PHP and be able to handle dynamic Flash input and export to the chosen format. My client has a generous budget to buy software to do this.

If anyone can suggest a good software solution or indeed another method to achieve the same goal I would be eternally grateful...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I won't give the exact details of how to do this yet, but a brief outline of what you could do:

- User uploads video (or it's already on the server? I'm not sure)
- You use exec() or shell_exec() to run ffmpeg, which will convert the
  flash file to another output, depending on the user's choice.

What I would recommend is writing a bash script or something that takes a command line parameter of the output choice (and input file of course), converts the file, and returns the location of the new file. You can use the output of exec() or shell_exec() in PHP to return the location to the user and allow them to download the file.

If you would like more details on a certain aspect, please comment, but I'm not sure if you've already looked into this method, so for now it's just a suggestion.